# Recursive function defined as const raise error (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain to me why this code is working:

```
let recursive = () =>
{
    recursive();
}
```

and this one raise error:

```
const recursive = () =>
{
    recursive();
}
```

Error:

> Build:Variable 'recursive' is used before being assigned.

I thought that const should be used when variable will not change which is true in this case.
Does someone know, if this is expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time recursive function was called, the runtime will first add a new but same name variable in the stack